# How i do I remove JavaScript code from Google feed form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, feedburner

I have line of code for my email feed subscription 
But my we web page do not support JavaScript

```
<form style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:3px;text-align:center;" action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=Solinkng', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
  <p>Enter your email address:</p>
  <p><input type="text" style="width:140px" name="email"/></p>
  <input type="hidden" value="Solinkng" name="uri"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
  <p>Delivered by <a href="https://feedburner.google.com" target="_blank">FeedBurner</a></p>
</form>
```

My problem is there a way which the JavaScript line can be changed to PHP form ?

Big thank for your time glad to see solution

Comment: from where you are submitting this form?

Comment: Yes but at first I want any thing JavaScript code in the code above change